# Efficient loss on softmax output in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, softmax

When the number of classes is large (e.g., number of words in language models), the softmax cross-entropy loss computation is very expensive. There seems to be no efficient options in the [built-in losses](https://keras.io/losses/). Is there a way to compute this efficiently in Keras, or should I self-implement it and how to?

Comment: Softmax is not a loss function.

Comment: If you're using TensorFlow as a backend, presumably you could use [sampled_softmax_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sampled_softmax_loss) for approximate softmax -> cross entropy during training. Or use that as a starting point for re-implementing.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I use softmax loss as shorten of losses on the softmax output, such as cross-entropy loss.

Comment: @AllenLavoie Thanks, that is one option... I find it quite surprise that Keras does not support efficient losses in a more straight-forward way.